Two cylinders rolling without slipping on planks
I am struggling with the following setup.

This setup consists of three massless planks and two massive cylinders, as can be seen from the figure. The lower plank is pulled with a force $\boldsymbol F$ that causes an acceleration $\boldsymbol a$ to the right. The cylinders don't slip with respect to the planks.
Since the plank is massless, the net force acting on it must be zero, so the force $\boldsymbol F$ with which the plank is pulled must be counterbalanced by a frictional force exerted by the cylinder on the plank to the left. By Newton's 3rd law, there must be a force $\boldsymbol f_{n}^{\text{below, above}}$ exerted by the plank on the cylinder towards the right. So far I have understood this reasoning. The cylinder rotates counterclockwise.
By rotating counterclockwise, does not the cylinder exert a force on the axis above it to the left? This, again by Newton's 3rd law, should be counterbalanced by a force to the right. Why does the diagram depict the leftward force exerted on the cylinder by the plank above, i.e. $\boldsymbol f_{n}^{{\text{above, below}}}$?
The top cylinder should behave in the same way as the bottom one.
I would like detailed answers on the reason for the direction of the forces acting on the system.
